# Ошибка в Android SqlLite

Tags: android, sql

Код:

```
db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();// открываем подключение к базе данных
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +" (" + COLUMN_NAME + ", " + COLUMN_YEAR  + ") VALUES ("+name.getText()+" , "+year.getText()+");");
userCursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);//Переместили данные в курсор
textBD.setText(String.valueOf(userCursor.getCount()));//вывели количество записей
String[] from = new String[] { COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_YEAR};
userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,//Первым параметром выступает контекст, с которым ассоциируется адаптер, например, текущая activity
        android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,  //Второй параметр - ресурс разметки интерфейса, который будет использоваться для отображения результатов выборки
        userCursor,//Третий параметр - курсор
        from, //Четвертый параметр - список столбцов из выборки, которые будут отображаться в разметке интерфейса
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1,//Пятый параметр - элементы внутри ресурса разметки, которые будут отображать значения столбцов из четвертого параметра
                android.R.id.text2}, // Шестой параметр - флаг
        0);//
listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
if (userCursor!=null) {//Проверяем пустой ли курсор
    if (userCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!userCursor.isAfterLast())       {
            int i = 0;
              column_name[i] = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));//создали перменную и в конце указали из какой колонки берем данные
            // двигаемся к следующему значению
            userCursor.moveToNext();//переходим на след. значение
            i++;
        }
    }
}
textBD.setText(column_name[1]);
userCursor.close();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "ОКЕЙ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
}
});
```

Ошибка:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed
>   object: SQLiteQuery: select * from users
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
>                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:152)
>                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:124)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:214)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:245)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:389)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 12-01
>   12:45:49.871 1516-1799/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force
>   finishing activity com.example.mysql_legkosuka/.MainActivity

Comment: в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Я не знаю, выбрасывает только это без указания конкретного места кода.

Answer (score 1):

> Attempt to re-open an already closed object.

Я думаю вы закрываете соединение с БД, а потом в какой-то момент опять пытаетесь подсоединиться к БД. Вам нужно пересоздать соединение.

Comment: Соединение вообще не закрывается в коде .